# asp button in dialog not handeling click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

vb:

```
 Protected Sub edit_content_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles edit_content.Click
    MsgBox("dasfaf")
End Sub
```

asp:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
       <a href="#" class="table-actions-button ic-table-edit" id="create-user"></a>
   </ItemTemplate> 
  </asp:TemplateField> 


 <div id="dialog-form" title="Edit Content" style="width:1001px;">
 <div>
    <asp:Button ID="edit_content" runat="server" Text="Edit Content" class="buttons" />
</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#create-user").button().click(function () {
$("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
```

my problem is that i'm putting an asp button in the jquery form to be abel to do some code in vb when the button is clicked... but the problem is that when i click on the button it does not go to the click event... if i put the button outside the dialog everything works... but i need it in the dialog ...

so how can i manage that?

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is an issue.

There is a workaround for this though.

Add the following Javscript code to the page/control.

```
 function Test2() {
        <%=Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(edit_content, "")%> 

    }
```

And in your html add the javascript call:-

```
 <asp:Button ID="edit_content" runat="server"  OnClientClick="return Test2();" Text="Edit Content"  class="buttons" />
```

It should work.

Comment: i'm getting that test2() is not defined.. what shall i do?

Comment: Well have you added the javascript function to the page or control. And i hope its Test2() with a capital T

Comment: what do you mean? i added the function in the script body in my asp page

Comment: Well then it should not give Test2() is not defined error because you have defined it. Just make sure about the casing, javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: okey it worked.. but when posting back i'm loosing the data in my dialog... so how can i handle the click event and get the data filled in the dialog form?

Comment: Well, im not sure how jquery dialog is affecting the normal asp.net functionality. However if you are losing data in the dialog after postback, try repopulating it in the button click event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your jQuery to be like this:

```
 $("#create-user").click(
    function () 
    {
        var dlg = $("#dialog-form").dialog();
        dlg.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
    });
```

I've tested it and it correctly calls the button click event server side.

**Update:** Here's the complete page I used to test this, this is in the default page created in an ASP.net application.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <input id="create-user" type="button" value="button" />

    <div id="dialog-form" title="Edit Content" style="width:1001px;">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </div>
    </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $("#create-user").click(
            function () {
                var dlg = $("#dialog-form").dialog();
                dlg.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
            });
    </script>

</asp:Content>
```

Code behind:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: when i changed my jquery the dialog doesn't open at all and if i add `dialog("open")` to the jquery the dialog  opens but i can't use any of the tools in it how can i fix it?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the complete source code listing.